# Core animation animating the layer to flip horizontally

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

I have two views and I want to switch between the two view using core animation, animating the layer of each of the views. The animation I want is like the one provided by `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft` but I could not manage to do it. I could make the layer rotate 180 and then when the animation stop I transition to the next view. How can this be done?

I used the code as below:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
self.view.layer.zPosition = 100;
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0);
[animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
[animation setDuration:.5];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
[animation setDelegate:self];

[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"test"];
```

and in the delegate I transition to the next view. But, this does not make much sense and the animation is not as lively as provided by the default animation. how can this be achieved?

Comment: What was wrong with `...FlipFromLeft`? When you say "is not as lively" what is it that you want the animation to do?

Comment: I just want to try it using the core animation. The animation does not seem to be natural like that in the default animation and I when one view rotates completely only then I add the second view. I feel that the default animation is not just rotating the view in 3d space. What kind of animation should be done and what am I missing here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## How to make it look like a 3D rotation

Your rotation doesn't look like it happens in 3D space because there is no perspective to your transform. Change the `m34` value of the transform into something small like 1.0/800.0 and you should see it rotate with perspective.

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0);
transform.m34 = 1.0/800.0;
[animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
```

That value (third column, forth row) of the 3D transform controls the perspective of the transform. You can read more about [3D projection on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) if you want to know more about how it works.

## How to flip two views as if they were to sides of a card

To have it seem like the two views are two sides of the same view you should add them rotate the back side π degrees and change the layer's [`doubleSided`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/doubleSided) property to NO for both layers. Now they won't be visible when facing away from you. As you apply the rotation to both the front and back layer they will change which layer is visible. Note: rotate the front to π degrees and the back to 2π so that it completes it rotation and faces you.

Comment: Well the problem here is the view rotates along the y-axis and so the view seems to be cut in the middle while rotating. The idea you gave was impressive but the default animation does it such that the anchor point of rotation is set at some other point. I tried doing the same with changing the anchor point to 0,.5 . But, this also changes the view coordinte itself. I am kind of stuck in this.

Comment: The layer is drawn relative to the anchor point. If (0,0.5) gave you the correct animation but the wrong position then you can simply set the frame after setting the anchor point.

Comment: But, I need a 3d rotation in which the first layer first rotates and then when it reaches 180 degree, it gets removes and the second layer starts from 180 to 360 degrees. Is it possible to add or remove layer in the middle of the animation. Or what is the best approach for doing this ?

Comment: Hi, I'm having this exact problem, @Sandeep please share what you ended up using if you solved it using core animation. I can't use transitionWithView because I'm setting the rotation using pan gesture

Comment: @Lukas : I would probably put both layers inside of a CATransformLayer (with the back already rotated 180 degrees) and then rotate the transform layer 360 degrees. If the two layers are not double sided, then that will give you the effect that it sounds like you are after.

Comment: DavidRönnqvist : Thanks a lot for your comment, How would you go about adding two sublayers and make sure one is on front side and the other at the back. I can think of using an extension on CATransformLayer to do something like bringLayerToFront but that would mean I'll need to know when rotation is 90 degrees. Can you please let me know if there is any way to actually set the layers back and front on CATransformLayer? 
@Sandeep It'd be cool if you can share how you solved it, huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

you could use

```
    [UIView transitionFromView:aView
                    toView:bView
                  duration:0.3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                }
 ];
```

i find you want to have both views within the same super-view else things get a bit messy.

Comment: Yes, but this method did not work for me and so I tried the other version of the UIView animation. [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
        [self.view: new.view];
    } completion:nil];

The former had some problem but this works good just to switch between two views. By the way, I wanted to do it with core animation.