# Mixing GCD with view animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, grand-central-dispatch

I want to do three view animations, staggered a little.  To do this I' mixing GCD and the view animation as follows...

**EDIT** - I'd like to do a flip animation with the children of viewA, then viewB, then viewC.  I'd like these animations to overlap...

```
random external action causes:  A-----------A'
                                    B-----------B'
                                        C---------C'
```

The trouble is, when a triggering action occurs during the A->C' animation, the states of the three get mixed up.  I'd like a way of doing the three staggered actions as a single, uninterrupted action.

```
- (void)flipAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    // views A,B,C are initialized here
    // kFLIPDURATION is 0.8
    NSTimeInterval interval = (animated)? kFLIPDURATION / 2.0 : 0;

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self flipChildrenOfView:viewA animated:animated];
    });
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self flipChildrenOfView:viewB animated:animated];
    });
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2*interval * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self flipChildrenOfView:viewC animated:animated];
    });
}

- (void)flipChildrenOfView:(UIView *)parent animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // some setup here to get visible and hidden views    
    [UIView transitionFromView:visibleView
                        toView:hiddenView
                      duration:((animated)? kFLIPDURATION : 0)
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                    completion:nil];
}
```

This works fine, except there are timer events and sometimes user actions driving these, and every so often, `flipAnimated:` is called while the animations are underway.  The result is mixed up views and sadness.

What I tried so far was (1) reading and them becoming confused about GCD alternatives. (2) I tried an instance variable called `animating`, added a completion block to my view animation calling method, then did this...

```
@property(assign,nonatomic) BOOL animating;

- (void)flipAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.animating) return;
    self.animating = YES;
    NSTimeInterval interval = (animated)? kFLIPDURATION / 2.0 : 0;

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self flipChildrenOfView:viewA animated:animated completion:nil];
    });
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self flipChildrenOfView:viewB animated:animated completion:nil];
    });
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2*interval * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self flipChildrenOfView:viewC animated:animated completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self.animating = NO;
        }];
    });
}
```

But alas, same behavior.  I could observe the block seeming to work with NSLogs, but the views would still get mixed up.  (With a second flip starting before a prior one was done).  I assume this is because I got in over my head on concurrency.

Would sure appreciate a helping hand, especially a code example.  --- Almost forgot: what would be even better than stoping concurrent requests, would be to have it queued and then run after the running is finished.

Comment: `hiddenView` is different in cases A, B, & C, right?

Comment: yes.  A,B,C are siblings.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for `transitionFromView:...` do say "The view transition starts immediately unless another animation is already in-flight, in which case it starts immediately after the current animation finishes."  So overlapping animation won't work like this.

Drop to CoreAnimation, e.g. CATransform3D, see [Core animation animating the layer to flip horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907380/core-animation-animating-the-layer-to-flip-horizontally).

Comment: Thanks.  I can do the flip fine (and it looks doable in quartz, too), but the problem I'm having is blocking more than one of these from running at a time.  Do you have a suggestion about that?

Comment: I'm now confused as to the desired outcome of your code with regards to timing.

Comment: Ah - your question made me think harder.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@GrahamPerks asked me to clarify the question, and doing so clarified my thinking.  In case this can help someone else, here's what I did.

The code was initializing the subviews to animate with the same staggered timing as the flips.  When the code was re-entered, it was examining the view hierarchy in a partially changed state.

The fix was to decide about transition views up front, not during, the three step animation...

```
- (void)flipAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    // views A,B,C are initialized here

    // FIX: but also initialize six views here
    UIView *viewAVisible, *viewAHidden, *viewBVisible, *viewBHidden, *viewCVisible, *viewCHidden;

    // FIX: refactor my animation wrapper to take the two views to transition

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self flipFrom:viewAHidden to:viewAVisible animated:animated];
    });
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self flipFrom:viewBHidden to:viewBVisible animated:animated];
    });
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2*interval * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self flipFrom:viewCHidden to:viewCVisible animated:animated];
    });
}
```

Now when a new animation request comes in concurrently, the views are in a coordinated state (because I think UIKit makes the change called for by the animation immediately).